# Facebook share directly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a sharing hover effect on my YouTube videos. So when you click "Del på Facebook/Share" it shares the article on Facebook. But when you click the "Del på Facebook/Share" on the video, the pop-up first shows the link, where you can press "Del/Share" when you click that, it redirects you to where you can share the article with picture and text.

How do i fix it, so that you don't have to click "Del/share" before you get redirected to the right sharing page?

[Look at the video in the bottom](http://sportbuzz.dk/scelerisque-diam-laoreet/)

```
$string .= '<ul class="share-video-overlay" id="share-video-overlay"><li class="facebook" id="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php"  onclick="window.open(\'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php\', \'newwindow\', \'width=490, height=150\'); return false;">Del på Facebook</a></li>';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook share button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337737/facebook-share-button)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a Share Dialog. Here is a document for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog