# in php how to share posts on face book from my website. there occur some error in using share button

Tags: php

i want to share things from my website on facebook.share button have to be used. But there is some error and only index page of the website is shared.

Comment: Add the code you have tried and what error you are getting

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>

Comment: in this i can only share the page........... i want to share things in my database

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I would strongly suggest that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and what we expect from a question.

Comment: that means, i couldn't get an answer from u na?????????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook share button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337737/facebook-share-button)

Answer (score 0):

Refer following links:

[Facebook share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)

[Sharing your content on facebook](https://huebris.com/facebook-share-button/)

[Share on the web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web)